# Universal Analytics tag firing but only some pageviews are recorded

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am experiencing a rather odd problem with my GA setup. Long story short, everything was working smoothly up until few days ago when an external developer implemented a bunch if changes to my [blog](https://blog.blacklane.com/) and since then only a small fraction of the sessions is being recorded.

- Setup is done via GTM and the Universal Analytics Tag, firing on all
  pages
- The Blog is tracked as separate view within the main website property
  and is a subdomain
- The only filter in use is inclusion of a hostname rule with a pattern
  blog.blacklane.com, which was working just fine till now
- GA Tag is firing properly in preview mode on all pages on GTM, yet no
  active sessions can be seen in real time view
- For some reason this is not the case with Safari and some Chrome
  versions, and there I can see my active session in real time view
  almost immediately
- We tried adding the GA snippet manually into the  of every page
  and problem was instantly resolved, data was running smoothly, so we definitely ruled out a filtering issue
- Only the Blog View seems affected by this issue, it's business as
  usual for our main domain
- All other tags firing through GTM seem to be working without any
  issues, including our internal tracking
- Last GTM change we did was over 15 days ago

We've been going back and forth with the developer for some time now, him claiming that there is nothing he can do as the problem is with out GTM, however, I find the coincidence weird that the blog subdomain, which he was optimizing for page performance end of last week is the only one affected and the tracking glitch happened exactly around that time.

From what I can tell, the tag is firing fine but for some reason GA is not receiving the data in the majority of cases.

Any support on the topic would be highly appreciated!

Comment: I had a quick look at the site, the GA tag didn't trigger, I see that there is some configuration, but to be sure, I would need access. There is just too much stuff configured in there

Comment: Interesting, how do you catch the tag not firing? At least in preview mode,  it seems to [work fine](https://imgur.com/L0lWyLb) for me.

Comment: Maybe you did changes that you haven’t published yet? You can use GOogle Tag assistant chrome extension to test live. Also you can look in the network tab in dev tools for “collect”.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, unfortunately it's not as straight forward as not publishing changes. Further investigation showed that the GA tag, which normally fires on Page View is [failing](https://imgur.com/a/veTnH0d) to do so for some reason. It does eventually fire but much later, which explains why only some page view events are being tracked. However, the reason for the failed firing is still a mystery to me.

Comment: Have you tried seeing what the [Google Analytics Debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna) prints to your Chrome's console?

Comment: Oh, and there is something in your GTM implementation that doesn't work, presumably Optimizely: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined ...
    at initNewOptimizelyIntegration ... at gtm.js?id=GTM-K88QGD:2116 ...`